# Multiples Sesiones en Java Web?

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans-8.2

Buenos días tengan todos ustedes.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo un sistema de impresión de Cupones para sorteos,hecho en NetBeans(Servlets) , este sistema tiene la opcion de loguearse e ingresar, hasta ahi todo funciona bien. El problema empieza cuando al momento de registrar los cupones por cliente por ejemplo yo registro 5000 creditos y me imprime 5 cupones, pero cuando otro usuario se loguea y registra los creditos de otro cliente creo yo que entra en conflicto interno y arroja un valor null, vi por internet que el servidor Apache Tomcat maneja internamente los usuarios conectados al sistema , tambien vi que para ese tipo de sistema multi-usuarios se tiene que trabajar con Hilos(Thread), por favor mi duda seria esa. 
Que me recomiendan hacer ?

---

Este es el error que me imprime.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo para loguearme.

```
public int idUsuario(entusuario enti) {
    int id=0;
    try {

        ps=xcone.prepareStatement("select idPersona from operador where nombreusuario=(?) and claveusuario=(?)");
        //ps=cone.xconMysql().prepareStatement("select idPersona from operador where nombreusuario=(?) and claveusuario=(?)");
        ps.setString(1, enti.getNombreusuario());
        ps.setString(2, enti.getClaveusuario());
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            id=rs.getInt(1);
        }
        //System.err.println("el id del cliente es "+id);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println("Error al otbener el id del cliente "+e.getMessage());
    } 

    return id;
}

public ArrayList<entusuario> getPersona(int id){
    ArrayList<entusuario> datos=new ArrayList<>();

    try {
            ps=xcone.prepareStatement("select per.idpersona,\n" +
            //ps=cone.xconMysql().prepareStatement("select per.idpersona,\n" +
        "per.nombres,\n" +
            "per.apellidos,\n" +
            "op.idoperador,\n" +
            "op.nombreusuario,\n" +
            "soc.idSocio,\n" +
            "soc.nombreSocio \n" +
            "from persona per\n" +
            "inner join operador op on per.idPersona=op.idpersona \n" +
            "inner join socio soc on soc.idSocio=op.idSocio \n"+
            "where per.idPersona=(?)");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            ent=new entusuario();
            ent.setIdpersona(rs.getInt(1));
            ent.setNombres(rs.getString(2));
            ent.setApellidos(rs.getString(3));
            ent.setIdoperador(rs.getInt(4));
            ent.setNombreusuario(rs.getString(5));
            ent.setIdSocio(rs.getInt(6));
            ent.setNombreSocio(rs.getString(7));
            datos.add(ent);
            System.err.println("Usuario "+ent.getNombres()+" logueado");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al obtener datos del usuario "+e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return datos;
}
```

A lo que pude entender es que se esta conectando muchas veces a la BD.

Comment: puedes agregar el fragmento del código donde te arroja el valor null y la secuencia de usuarios que ingresan? Cómo creas la variable xcone? por ahí estas creando una nueva conexión a la base de datos (y nunca las cierras) cada vez que creas un usuario se conecta. prueba luego de realizar la query, realizar xcone.close() para evitar tener muchas conexiones simultaneas a ver si funciona!

Comment: Puedes intentar usando un framework como spring que maneja tu pool de conexiones y evitas esos problemitas hehhe

Comment: Una consulta al cerrar la conexión en la función que me retorna un ArrayList, hace que el valor me retorne nulo, entonces en que parte exactamante podria cerrar la conexion??

Answer (score 1):

Te adjunto una forma de realizar la consulta que te debería solucionar los problemas:

```
public ArrayList<entusuario> getPersona(int id){
ArrayList<entusuario> datos=new ArrayList<>();

try {
        Statment stmt = xcone.createStatment();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(/*tu consulta*/);

    while(rs.next())
    {
        ent=new entusuario();
        ent.setIdpersona(rs.getInt(1));
        ent.setNombres(rs.getString(2));
        ent.setApellidos(rs.getString(3));
        ent.setIdoperador(rs.getInt(4));
        ent.setNombreusuario(rs.getString(5));
        ent.setIdSocio(rs.getInt(6));
        ent.setNombreSocio(rs.getString(7));
        datos.add(ent);
        System.out.println("Usuario "+ent.getNombres()+" logueado");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println("Error al obtener datos del usuario "+e.getMessage());
    return null;
} finally(){
    //se agrega un bloque finally, para asegurar (no importa si el flujo del programa
    //fue o no el correcto) cerrar la conexión completamente y dejar limpio el sistema
    if(rs !=null) rs.close();
    if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
    if(xcone !=null) xcone.close();
}
return datos;
}
```

Ahora bien, asegurate de volver a crear una conexion a mysql si te realizan otra solicitud, ya que la conexión fue cerrada (tienes que crear una nueva). Prueba ahí y me cuentas. Espero que te funcione. Sino lo hace, agrega el código donde creas la conexión en "xcone". Saludos!